# JTable resize only selected column when container size changes

Tags: java, swing, resize, jtable

For a JTable that's inside a panel, if the panel is made larger, how can I distribute the extra space to only certain columns (in my case, to the last column, though it may be nice to offer "columns 3,4, and 8 will get the extra space).

I want to allow the user to change column sizes for all the columns manually.

I tried table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_LAST_COLUMN);
That distributes the extra space to all the columns that are resizeable when the JTable is resized.  In the the JavaDoc for JTable, for doLayout(), says:

> When the method is called as a result of the resizing of an enclosing window, the resizingColumn is null. This means that resizing has taken place "outside" the JTable and the change - or "delta" - should be distributed to all of the columns regardless of this JTable's automatic resize mode.

There may be a way to intercept a "JTable is resizing" event, and do something custom, though I haven't been able to figure it out.

Another solution is presented in
[How to exclude columns from auto-resizing in a JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469739/how-to-exclude-columns-from-auto-resizing-in-a-jtable)
Though it doesn't really tell me how to do it in swing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the `doLayout()` method to intercept the layout. This gives the basics. You will need to determine what you want to do when the last column width is about to go negative.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class Test2Table
{
    private static Object[][] data = new Object[][]
    {
            { "a", "b", "c" },
            { "d", "e", "f" }
    };
    private static Object[] colNames = new Object[] { "1", "2", "3" };

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JTable table = new JTable(data, colNames)
                {
                    @Override
                    public void doLayout()
                    {
                        //  Viewport size changed. Change last column width

                        if (tableHeader != null
                        &&  tableHeader.getResizingColumn() == null)
                        {
                            TableColumnModel tcm = getColumnModel();
                            int delta = getParent().getWidth() - tcm.getTotalColumnWidth();
                            TableColumn last = tcm.getColumn(tcm.getColumnCount() - 1);
                            last.setPreferredWidth(last.getPreferredWidth() + delta);
                            last.setWidth(last.getPreferredWidth());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            super.doLayout();
                        }
                    }

                };

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks.  Using this solution, it gives all the extra "slack" space to the last column, ignoring the "preferred" sized of each column, especially on the initial display of the columns.  I would like to include mKorbel's method too: honor the preferred widths if possible (only needed on the initial display of the table?), and distribute any slack to the last column when the table's container is resized.  I came up with a few (incomplete) hacks.  Are there any simple/elegant solutions?

Comment: Also found http://developer.classpath.org/doc/javax/swing/JTable-source.html  which is useful (see the doLayout() section), but don't want to reinvent that entire wheel if I don't have to.

Comment: `I would like to honor the preferred widths if possible (only needed on the initial display of the table?),` - This is the way the code works. Change the above example to use setSize(400, 200), instead of using pack(). The first two columns are displayed at their preferred width of 75 and the remaining space goes to the third column.

Answer (score 3):

- see constant `table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);`
- default widht is 80px
- can to prepare initial size, more in Oracle tutorial [Setting and Changing Column Widths](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#width)