# Calculating the widest column of a JTable

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable, autoresize

I have a `JTable` object that shows all the contents of a pre-selected MySQL table. As you will know, this class provides functionalities like columns-auto-resizing: i would like to create a procedure that calculates the sum of the width of all the cells contained inside the table and turns on the AUTO RESIZE mode if the result is minor than its `preferredWidth`. I've been trying to follow hundreds of online guides, but my procedure doesn't still work:

```
public void setTableColumnPreferredWidth(javax.swing.JTable aTable)
{
    int width = 0;
    int TotalWidth = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < aTable.getRowCount(); row++)
    {
        for (int myColumn=0;myColumn < aTable.getColumnCount();myColumn++)
        {
            TableCellRenderer renderer = aTable.getCellRenderer(row, myColumn);
            Component comp = aTable.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, myColumn);
            width = Math.max (comp.getPreferredSize().width, width);
            aTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(myColumn).setPreferredWidth(width);
        }
    }

    for (int I=0;I<aTable.getColumnModel().getColumnCount();I++)
        TotalWidth += aTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(I).getPreferredWidth();

    int maximum = 0;

    if (MainTable.getAutoResizeMode() == MainTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS)
        maximum = MainTable.getPreferredSize().width;
    else
    {
        int PreviousAutoresize = MainTable.getAutoResizeMode();
        MainTable.setAutoResizeMode(MainTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
        maximum = MainTable.getPreferredSize().width;
        MainTable.setAutoResizeMode(PreviousAutoresize);
    }

    if (maximum < TotalWidth) 
        MainTable.setAutoResizeMode(MainTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
    else 
        MainTable.setAutoResizeMode(MainTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
}
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: As it is now, your code is changing the columns' width before it determines the width of the largest one, I'm not sure if that is what you want to do.

Comment: It used to retreive table columns' width without changing it. Are you referring to the auto resize mode handling?

Comment: This `aTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(myColumn).setPreferredWidth(width);` changes the column's width and before that you have this `width = Math.max (comp.getPreferredSize().width, width);` which I guess it is used to determine the width of the biggest column. If that is the case, you  will need to first determine the biggest width and only after that change the width of all the columns to that value.

Answer (score 1):

> i would like to create a procedure that calculates the sum of the width of all the cells contained inside the JTable and turns on the AUTO RESIZE mode if the result is minor than its preferredWidth

The auto resize property should be based on the space available in the viewport of the scrollpane that is displaying the table.

This would need to be done dynamically as the size of the scroll pane changes.

You can add a `ComponentListener` to the scrollpane and listen for the `componentResized` event. Then you do your calculation:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public SSCCE()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        JTable table = new JTable(5, 5);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        add( scrollPane );

        scrollPane.addComponentListener( new ComponentAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)
            {
                JScrollPane scrollPane = (JScrollPane)e.getComponent();
                JTable table = ((JTable)scrollPane.getViewport().getView());

                int tableWidth = table.getPreferredSize().width;
                int viewportWidth = scrollPane.getViewport().getSize().width;

                if (tableWidth < viewportWidth)
                    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
                else
                    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new SSCCE());
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

Or another option is to override a bit of the default layout processing of the JTable as demonstrated in: [JTable resize only selected column when container size changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368343/jtable-resize-only-selected-column-when-container-size-changes/16369479#16369479)